# How to say don't leave the door open when you leave!

Tags: sentence-construction, idiomatic-language

Basically, I want to say something like

- Don't leave the door open when you leave the office.

However, this sounds a bit awkward in my opinion because it has two leaves in a row. So, I thought about the other possible ways and came up with the following sentences.

> Don't leave the door open if you are not going to be inside the office for a while.
>
> Don't leave the door open if you are not going to be here for while.

They look to me as a bit wordy. I am wondering what is the common or idiomatic ways to say this.

Comment: Those last two sentences equate to '*Leave the door open if you're going to be here for a while*' which might be the opposite of what you actually want to say? (Also James K's answer +1)

Comment: @Smock hmm, I just don't want the office to be open while no one is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While there is nothing very bad about the repetition of leave,
there is a very simple solution: You can change "don't leave the door open" to "close the door".

> Close the door when you leave the office.